# which is best practice to write to handle error handling then-catch or try-catch in javascript / node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, try-catch

I have a doubt I wrote a program and I am confused what to use to handle if any error occur in my loop and which is best practice to write to handle error handling

should I use `then catch` or `try catch` in my `for of` loop as the output

```
for (value of Data){

test = await getValue(value)
       .then((obj)=>{
         // some code})
       .catch((err)=>{
         console.log(err);});
}
```

```
for (value of Data){
 try{
 test= await getValue(value);
 }
 catch (e){
  console.log(e);
}
```

Ps: down vote welcome but need proper explanation which is best practise to write

Comment: mixing `async`/`await` with `.then` `.catch` in a single function is (almost) always bad code - pick one and stick with it

Comment: This is a personal preference.  Usually, you would use `try/catch` with `await` and `.catch()` when not using `await`, but there are exceptions.  Also, you would generally NOT use `.then()` when using `await`.  The whole point of `await` is to avoid `.then()` and the nested code it causes.

Comment: so should i go with try catch ? @Bravo

Comment: see previous comment by jfriend00 - it's not up to me, it's not up to him, it's purely up to you - of the two pieces of code, the second is arguably "better" as it's not mixing async/await with .then/.catch - so in that respect - make your mind up

Comment: got it @jfriend00 :)

Comment: Inside, your `for` loop, `await` vs. `.then()` gives completely different results.  One offers parallel running of asynchronous operations, the other offers sequential running of asynchronous operations.  So, you use the one that gives you the behavior you want.  Then, pick the error handling method that matches (`try/catch` with `await` and `.catch()` with `.then()`).

Comment: yeah, hadn't even considered the `for` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.catch()` vs. `try/catch` is somewhat a personal preference and it also depends upon how you want the code to run.  Usually, you would use `try/catch` with `await` and `.catch()` when not using `await`, but there are exceptions.  Also, you would generally NOT use `.then()` when using `await`.  The whole point of `await` is to avoid `.then()` and the nested code it causes.

Inside, your `for` loop, `await` without a `.then()` vs. `.then()` with `await` gives completely different results.  One offers parallel running of asynchronous operations, the other offers sequential running of asynchronous operations as the `for` loop pauses until the `await` fulfills.

So, you use the one that gives you the behavior you want.  Then, pick the error handling method that matches (`try/catch` with `await` and `.catch()` with `.then()` - usually).

Comment: "*Inside your for loop, `await` vs. `.then()` gives completely different results.*" - OP had `await` in both snippets

Comment: @Bergi - Yes, and I've clarified my answer in that regard.  But, the spirit of the question was about `.catch()` vs. `try/catch`.